# HTable.get(List<Get>) results order

Tags: hbase

What is the order of the Result array returned by a call to `HTable.get(List<Get>)`?
I mean, is correct to assume that is the same order of the input list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order in the result array will be the same as the order of the input list. Like the batch method, the ordering of execution of the actions is not defined but the result will always be in the same order. Since it will have a null in the results array for gets that failed, it would have been difficult to determine which have failed without looking in each Result instance.